# AWK -- Select Random Record From A List

Tags: bash, random, awk, sed

I am trying to return a random word from `/usr/share/dict/words` on my *NIX machine. I have written the following script using BASH, AWK, and SED together to do it, but I feel like it should be writable using AWK alone by using the `RN` and `NF` fields somehow.

```
#!/bin/bash

get_secret_word () {
    awk '/^[A-Za-z]+$/ {if (length($1) > 3 && length($1) < 9) 
        print $1}' /usr/share/dict/words > /tmp/word_list
    word_list_length=$(wc -l /tmp/word_list | awk '{print $1}')
    random_number=$(( $RANDOM%$word_list_length ))
    secret_word=$(sed "${random_number}!d" /tmp/word_list)
    return $secret_word
}
get_secret_word
echo $secret_word
```

Any suggestions? I love AWK, and I'm trying to understand it better.

Comment: any reason to not use `shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/words` ?

Comment: Because I had no idea that tool existed. Thank you! I'd still like to know how to do it in AWK though.

Comment: you can simplify the first awk to `awk '/^[A-Za-z]+$/ && length()>3 && length()<9'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    srand('"$RANDOM"')
}
{
    if (/^[A-Za-z]+$/ && length() > 3 && length() < 9)
        words[i++] = $1
}
END {
    print words[int(rand() * i)]
}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Whether you store the words in memory or in a file will depend on your use case.
BR.

Comment: What function does the `"$RANDOM"` serve within the srand() command? Isn't srand() itself enough to reset the seed?

Comment: You're right.  The srand() uses current time of day as a new seed if no argument is provided.  The environment variable $RANDOM may be unnecessary.